# Java Generic Methods get Class from Returntype

Tags: java, generics, methods

I would like to create a mapper that reads the individual variables with the specification of two entity classes and passes the various data types (with content) to a converter, which then returns the data under various conditions.
My problem is that I am not yet 100% familiar with Java Generics and therefore need help how to determine the return types in the best possible/standardized way.

As far as I found out, I have to define a generic class or pass the class to the generic method, that should be correct, right? Because I had already tried to define a generic method without passing the class as a parameter and to determine the type from this is not supposed to work in Java.

Could you maybe show me an example, how a generic method determines the return type, if a generic class is available?

```
public abstract class Converter{
    public static <TInto, TFrom> TInto convertDataTypes(TFrom from){
        TInto into = null;
        /* My Try 
        Class<?> intoClass = (Class<?>) ((java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType Converter.class.getDeclaredMethods()[0]
                .getGenericReturnType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

        into = (TInto) intoClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        */
        // TODO: init into;
        // TODO: get into class
        return into;
    }
}
```

I also tried with the simple 'Type', because ParameterizedType throws an exception, but then 'getActualTypeArguments' doesn't work, or I still don't get the correct type (Boolean) that I want...

What I also didn't quite understand is why even if I specify the generic types, so when I call the generic method it doesn't recognize what I attach to the method.
Function call simply as Example:

```
Boolean b = Converter.<Boolean,String>convertDataTypes("true");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Java's type erasure makes it impossible to infer the generic type at runtime without explicitly passing the class. More formal:

> the generic type information is not retained at runtime due to type erasure, which removes all generic type information, replacing it with their bounds or with `Object` if the type parameters are unbounded.

So the typical way to handle this problem is indeed to pass the `Class` object of the desired return type to the method, let's try to create something for String->Integer for example:

```java
abstract class Converter {

    public static <TInto, TFrom> TInto convertDataTypes(TFrom from, Class<TInto> intoClass) {
        TInto into = null;

        if (intoClass == String.class && from instanceof Integer) {
            into = intoClass.cast(Integer.toString((Integer) from));
        } else if (intoClass == Integer.class && from instanceof String) {
            into = intoClass.cast(Integer.parseInt((String) from));
        }
        // maybe you'll have more converters here, depending on the given types

        return into;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
Integer i = Converter.convertDataTypes("41", Integer.class);
String s = Converter.convertDataTypes(41, String.class);
```